# Create Json array from MVC controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, json

everyone!
I have controller

```
public JsonResult GetPlacesJson()
       {
           var result = myplaces.GetAllPlaces();            //return List
           return Json(result,JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
       }
```

I need to create an JavaScript array with JSON objects using controller.I tried with $.getJson(...),but i didn't succeed.Could you help me?
Thanks!

Comment: do get a normal specifying the return

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
                JsonArray places = new JsonArray();

                for (String s : myplaces.GetAllPlaces();) {
                    places.add(new JsonPrimitive(s));
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

use following code to create Javascript array from json:

```
   <script>
   var rows = [];
   for (var i = 0; i < jsonresult.length; i++) {
   rows.push.apply(rows, jsonresult[i]);
     }
  </script>
```